# Why can't I pick up these corpses?

Tags: fallout-4

There are some molerat corpses hanging around my Red Rocket Station that I would like to get rid of. Most of the time, I just pickup up corpses and drag them away. However, I'm not allowed to pick these up for some reason.

The game tells me that they're too heavy. This seems odd, as I can pick up and drag around full-size humans.

How do I pick these corpses up and move them, so that I can dispose of them?

Before you suggest using the console, let me point out that I'm playing on XBox One.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I have a link to that question *in* the question. I didn't see any answers that would solve my problem without the console. I didn't want to edit their question to ask for non-console solutions, and don't see why anyone would post an additional non-console answer given that that one's already accepted.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Edited it to try and make it more clear why this would have different answers than that one.

Comment: This question is still a duplicate. The other question asks what you ask, its just that the answer does not apply to Xbox. Pwrhaps you should post a bounty?

Comment: @Timelord64 Geez. Alright, let me radically edit this, as the point I'm asking about really isn't covered in the other question.

Answer (score 2):

Corpses that are too heavy to drag with the physics button [may be lightened through dismemberment.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3t9mx4/fallout_4_mythbusters_episode_1/cx4njfm) Based on this behavior, I would surmise that boosting your strength through Buffout and related drugs may also prove effective.

Comment: I'll try those. For some reason it didn't occur to me that which objects I could move around would be related to my strength. Don't recall that being a factor in previous games.

Comment: I'd be interested to know this as well.

Comment: I can tell that you understood the question, as this is still a good answer after the edit. Assuming it's true. I haven't got a chance to try it yet.